# Maven assembly pattern matching

Tags: maven, design-patterns, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm having trouble with patterns in a fileset.
This explicit assembly works:

```
   <fileSet>
        <directory>stp-arina-adapter-ny-dev-d1</directory>
        <!-- <directory>*d1/**</directory> -->
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>target/*gz</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

But I need a more general solution

```
    <!-- <directory>*stp-arina-adapter-ny-dev-d1</directory> -->
    <directory>*d1</directory>
```

Using a wildcard I was hoping meant "directory ending in d1", I get

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive : You must set at least one file.
```

I've tried multiple combinations of directory and include, such as

```
<directory>.</directory>
<include>target/*.gz</include>
```

and

```
<include>**/*.gz</include>
```

with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html#class_fileSet),

> directory
>   Sets the absolute
>   or relative location from the module's
>   directory. For example, "src/main/bin"
>   would select this subdirectory of the
>   project in which this dependency is
>   defined.

So we cannot have wildcards for `<directory>`.  These should be valid

```
<directory>${basedir}</directory>
<directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
<directory>target</directory>
```

You could specify required wildcards using `<includes>`.